# Ревью первого кода

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Написал свой первый хеловорд! Как вам? Возможно ли улучшить?

```
#include <iostream>

auto main(int argc, char** argv) -> int {
    std::cout << "Hello, " <<  "world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Укоротить - так точно :)
`#include <iostream>
int main() {  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; }`

Comment: *"первый"* Да ну, не верю. Что это за книжка такая, в которой сразу с ходу предлагают `auto` `-> int`?

Comment: Корректнее возвращать не захардкоженное число, а `EXIT_SUCCESS`

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Раз уж умеешь в auto -> int, предлагаю продвинутый вариант ментального hello world-a:

`++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).